# How do I return a zip file to the browser via the response OutputStream?

Tags: java, zip, outputstream

In this situation, I have created a zip file containing search result files, and am trying to send it to the user. Here is the chunk of code I am currently trying to use.

```
File[] zippable = new File[files.size()];
File resultFile = ZipCreator.zip(files.toArray(zippable), results);
InputStream result = new FileInputStream(resultFile);
IOUtils.copy(result, response.getOutputStream());
```

However, this currently doesn't work quite right. Instead of returning the zip file that I have created, it returns an html file. If I manually change the file extension afterwards, I can see that the contents of the file are still the search results that I need. So the problem just lies in returning the proper extension to the response.

Does anyone have any advice for this situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Type` response header to the value `application/zip` (or `application/octet-stream`, depending on the target browser).  Additionally, you may want to send additional response headers indicating attachment status and filename.

Comment: I think I may be misinterpreting you here. I've added a line to the code, so it now reads `response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");`
Still no success though. This call is being made just before the call to IOUtils.copy

Comment: @Bennie: looks good, but again, there is some confusion about the "right" MIME type to use for a ZIP file, so you might want to play with those values.

Comment: Alright, it looks like it's working now, at least for returning the file. It's doing a strange thing though, where the file is called "exportZipSearchResults.htm.zip". Is there a built-in way to change the filename on the response?

Comment: @Bennie: try using the [`Content-Disposition` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) (possibly with value "inline") and a filename of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the content type header to `application/octet-stream` prior to streaming the results.  Depends on what implementation of `response` you are using on how you actually do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some working code, just in case anyone needs it:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        // The zip file you want to download
        File zipFile = new File(zipsResourcesPath + zipFileName);

        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipFileName);
        response.setContentLength((int) zipFile.length());

        try {

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
            OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            int bytes;
            while ((bytes = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                responseOutputStream.write(bytes);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Exception: " + e);
        }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<a class="btn" href="/path_to_servlet" target="_blank">Download zip</a>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please show how you defined the "zipFile" ? How you added files into this "zipFile"?

Comment: I've edited the code so you can see how the zipFile is defined. Please reconsider the downvote @Yithirash . I appreciate comments, as this helps me to improve my answers.

Comment: this is getting already created zip file. But how to get multiple files and make them into zip using Java? and then send to response.

Answer (score -1):

So I found a hack for this : ) Just add ".zip" in your filename and set your content type as application/zip. Works like a charm.

```
response.setContentType("application/zip");
String licenseFileName = eId;
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + licenseFileName +".zip");
```

Comment: what is eId in this example?

Comment: @BanAnanas eId was an identifier in my case. It's just the file name you want. It can be anything basically.